# Adding rows to database from a dynamic form in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form to index parts that belong to schematic drawings. We have hundreds of drawings and each one will have a different number of parts attached to it. Each part requires three pieces of information a number, part_id and Description. The initial form captures that and allows the user to add as many rows to the form as are needed to get all the parts from the drawing. The form fields are named Number_1, Part_id_1 and Description_1. Each row added to the form increments the number at the end by one. For example if a schematic has 10 parts I will end up with Number_1 - Number_10.

```
while ($i <= $Fieldnum) {
             $Number = "Number_".$i;
             $PartNumber = "PartNumber_".$i;
             $Description = "Description_".$i;
             print ("
           <input name=$Number type=\"text\" size=\"3\" />
           <input name=$PartNumber type=\"text\" size=\"20\"  />
           <input name=$Description type=\"text\" size=\"35\" />
                    ");
             $i++;
            }
```

Where I'm stuck is getting the data into the MySQL database. Each form row needs to become a row in the database. If this was a static form it would be easy, but with each form element having a dynamic name I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Why does the name of the input need to be a value of this part? What else are you using this name attribute for?

Comment: Couldn't you iterate over the POST data in the exact same way you iterate to generate the form rows?

Answer (score 0):

Use two tables.  Create a table for the schematic.  Create a table for parts, and assign a foreign key with the id of the schematic.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to do that.

Give all your inputs the same name for a given element adding `[]` so it ends up as an array server side.

Here is an example:

```
<input name='number[]' .../>
<input name='part_number[]' .../>
<input name='description[]' .../>
```

You can have as much of these as you want...

Then server side just iterate through them :

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['number']); $i++){
    $row = array();
    $row['number'] = $_POST['number'][$i];
    $row['part_number'] = $_POST['part_number'][$i];
    $row['description'] = $_POST['description'][$i];
    //do your mysql insert here.
}
```